# Calling another controller inside a form in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my app I have a case where a user can save a bill of lading from some form, or, send the same object to another controller.

My form is like this:

```
<%=content_for :detail do%>
  <%=form_for @bill_of_lading,:url => bill_of_ladings_path(),:html=>{:class=>"form-horizontal bol-form"} do |f|%>
    <%= render :partial => 'bill_of_ladings/form', :locals => {:f => f} %>
    <div class="form-actions">
      <%= button_to 'Create Draft', {:controller => "drafts", :action => "create", :bill_of_lading => @bill_of_lading }, :method=>:post ,:class=>"btn btn-warning"%>
      <%=f.submit "Create Bill of Lading", :class=>"btn btn-primary","data-loading-text"=>"Saving..."%> or <%=link_to "cancel",bill_of_ladings_path,:class => "btn"%>
    </div>
  <% end %>

<% end %>
```

I want that, when the user press the "Create Draft" button, the data was sent to the `DraftsController`, the create method, passing the `@bill_of_lading` object.

But when I pressed the "Create Draft" button, it goes to the default submit button (in this case, to the `bill_of_laddings_path`).

So, how can I do the Create Draft button works as I want? (calling another controller, but passing the data as parameter)

Thanks

Comment: by default, you cant do it with plain html and form. since type of submit button is assigned to "Create Bill ...", So solution is Javascript. Smth like, on button click do this $ajax request. Or you have to move out from form the button, then it will do what you want.

Comment: I moved it out from form, but it doesnt fill the @bill_of_lading parameter and then when the controller is called params[:bill_of_lading] comes null

Comment: Before writing an answer to your question I want to know why you want pass `@bill_of_lading` to another controller. What is your ultimate goal?

Comment: Hi Pavan. Basicly a bill_of_lading can be a Draft (to make some comparisons between clients, etc...) or can be a REAL bill of ladding. 

The businnes rules are differents when saving and deleting a draft and a bill of ladding. So, in this controller I can save (the same data) to be a REAL Bill of Ladding or only a Draft. I was clear?

Comment: The model its the same for drafts and bill of ladings. (bill_of_ladding.rb). The difference is only a boolean attribute called draft. So, In this view, the user will choose to save it as bill_of_ladding.draft -> true, and bill_of_ladding.draft -> false. 

The client want separated views for Drafts and Bill of Ladings (he dont want a filter on the same view, got it? )